# Quadratic Equations Vertex/Standard Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

At the moment I'm being taught how to convert Vertex Form into Standard form and Standard Form to Vertex. Now my last assigned problem has been a problem for me, we never went over this in class(Algebra), so I'd love for you to teach me.

> To line an irrigation ditch, a farmer will use rectangular metal
>   sheets. Each side will be bent x feet from the edge at an angle
>   of 90° to form the trough. If the sheets are 20 ft wide, how far
>   from the edge (x) should the farmer bend them to maximize
>   the area of a cross-section of the trough.

The formulas I've learnt now are: 
$$y=f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
$$y=f(h)=a(b(x-h))^2+k$$
$$h=\frac{-b}{2a}$$

I think I need to find x, but I don't know how to get there using everything I've learned so far, so please help me with this one.

Comment: What is the cross-section? Which way are you cutting it?

Comment: It doesn't elaborate at all! I'm in an Algebra class, so no calculus this time.

Comment: The question is very confusing then, for it does not state the thickness of the metal plates. If you are simply doing a horizontal cut across the 2 layers when it is bent, the thickness needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Hmmm I guess the question is just unsolvable using what I've learnt then...Thank You For your help!

Answer (score 0):

The cross section of the ditch will be a rectangle, lined on the vertical sides and bottom by the metal but open at the top.  If the bend is made $x$ feet from the edge, the two sides will have length $x$ while the bottom will have length $20-2x$.  So the area of the cross section is
$$
    f(x) = x(20-2x) = 20x-2x^2 
$$
The graph of $f$ is a parabola.  According to your formula, the vertex of that parabola is at $(5,50)$.